# NodeJS doesn't like passport + sequelize logins

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js, dom-events, passport.js

I'm going crazy with nodejs. I'm trying to realize the backend for a simple user management webapp powered by NodeJS, using Passport-Local and Sequelize libraries. Right now I just designed the user model. The main problem I have is that the signup process gives me an error: it looks like that I'm working on an undefined object. Could please someone help me in figuring out what's going on?

Here is my code (merged with some solutions I found on internet - obviously nothing works, according to Murphy's laws).

Could please Javascript programmers forgive me if the code is not good. My excuse is that it is my first programming attempt in Javascript, I MUST do it for a project and last (excuse) but not least I grew up with C and microchips.

ERROR:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'findOne' of undefined
> at Strategy._verify (/home/me/Documents/cerbero/config/passport.js:21:17)

app.js

```
var app = express();


//blabla favicon stuff

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));


app.use(session({ secret:'holaholaholaholaholaholahola',
                  resave:true,
                  saveUninitialized:true
                }));



app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
app.use(flash());

app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'pug');

var models = require("./models")
require('./config/passport.js')(passport, models.usermodel);

app.use('/', index);
app.use('/user', require('./routes/users')(passport));


models.sequelize.sync().then(function(){
  console.log("Database connected");
}).catch(function(err) {
  console.log(err, "Somenthing went wrong with the dbdbdb");
});

 //blabla listening stuff



module.exports = app;
```

models/usermodel.js

```
    module.exports = function(sequelize, Sequelize) {
  var User = sequelize.define('user', {

        id: {
            autoIncrement: true,
            primaryKey: true,
            type: Sequelize.INTEGER
        },

        username: {
            type: Sequelize.TEXT
        },

        public_key: {
            type: Sequelize.TEXT
        },

        email: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING,
            validate: {
                isEmail: true
            }
        },

        password: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING,
            allowNull: false
        },

        last_login: {
            type: Sequelize.DATE
        },

    });

    return User;
}
```

routes/users.js

```
var express = require('express');

module.exports = function(passport, user) {
  var router = express.Router();

  //blablabla other routes
  router.get('/signup', function(req,res,next) {
    res.render('signup', {message: req.flash('signupMessage')});
  });


  router.post('/signup', passport.authenticate('local-signup', {
    successRedirect: '/user/dashboard',
    failureRedirect: '/user/signup'}
  ));

  router.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local'), function(req, res) {
    res.redirect('/');
  });



  return router;
};

function isLogged(req, res, next) {
  if (req.isAuthenticated())
    return next();

  res.redirect('/');
};
```

EDIT
I forgot passport strategy.
passport.js

```
var bCrypt = require('bcrypt-nodejs');


module.exports = function(passport, user) {

    var User = user;
    var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
    console.log('debug: sono nella routine');


    passport.use('local-signup', new LocalStrategy(

        {
            usernameField: 'email',
            passwordField: 'password',
            passReqToCallback: true
        },
        function(req, email, password, done) {
          

            User.findOne({
                where: {
                    email: email
                }
            }).then(function(user) {
                if (user) {
                  return done(null, false, {message: req.flash('email already taken')});
                  console.log('mail already taken');
                }
                else {
                    var pass = generateHash(password);

                    var data =

                        {
                            email: email,
                            password: pass,
                            username: req.body.username,
                            public_key: '0',
                            last_login: null

                        };

                    User.create(data).then(function(newUser, created) {

                        if (!newUser) {

                            return done(null, false);

                        }

                        if (newUser) {

                            return done(null, newUser, {message: req.flash('tappost')});

                        }

                        next();

                    });

                }

            });

        }

    ));

    passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {

        User.findById(id).then(function(user) {

            if (user) {

                done(null, user.get());

            } else {

                done(user.errors, null);

            }

        });

    });


    passport.serializeUser(function(user,done) {
      done(null, user.id);
    });

var generateHash = function(password) {
                return bCrypt.hashSync(password, bCrypt.genSaltSync(8), null);
              };
```

Comment: The error is from your passport.js file, but that is the one file you didn't include for us to review!

Comment: You're right. I edited the question. Now you can find the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. 
"Just" changed how to reference the model in passport.js as follow

```
var User = user;
```

had to rewritten as

```
var User = db.user;
```

Here the definitive passport strategy file

```
const db = require('./../models/');
var bCrypt = require('bcrypt-nodejs');


module.exports = function(passport) {

    var User = db.user;
    var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;

    passport.use('local-signup', new LocalStrategy(

        {
            usernameField: 'email',
            passwordField: 'password',
            passReqToCallback: true
        },
        function(req, email, password, done) {
          var generateHash = function(password) {
            return bCrypt.hashSync(password, bCrypt.genSaltSync(8), null);
          };

            User.findOne({
                where: {
                    email: email
                }
            }).then(function(user) {
                if (user) {
                  return done(null, false, {message: req.flash('email already taken')});
                  console.log('mail already taken');
                }
                else {
                    var pass = generateHash(password);

                    var data =

                        {
                            email: email,
                            password: pass,
                            username: req.body.username,
                            public_key: '0',
                            last_login: null

                        };

                    User.create(data).then(function(newUser, created) {

                        if (!newUser) {

                            return done(null, false);

                        }

                        if (newUser) {

                            return done(null, newUser, {message: req.flash('tappost')});

                        }

                    });

                }

            }).catch(function(err) {
              console.log(err);
            });

        }

    ));


    passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
            done(null, user.id);
        });

        passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
            User.findById(id).then(function(user){
                done(null, user);
            }).catch(function(e){
                done(e, false);
            });
        });




}
```

Comment: Hi i want to do passportJS login and signup function can you share me any tutorials or blogs regarding the same?